# If Internal energy can be changed by doing work also, then how come internal energy is zero in a isothermal process involving non zero work?

Tags: thermodynamics

In the equation of First law of thermodynamics

$∆U = q + w$,

where $U$ is the internal energy, $q$ is the heat supplied and $w$ is the work done.

It is said that *for an isothermal process, since the temperature remains constant, the change in internal energy is zero even if the work done is non zero.*

On the other hand, thermodynamics also says that *internal energy can be changed by doing work*.

So supposing for a particular process the work is not zero in the above equation, then shouldn't the internal energy also be non-zero?

I don't get it why such type of consideration is taken while solving problems of the type given below:

> 29. An ideal gas undergoes isothermal compression from 5 m³ to 1 m³ against a constant external pressure of 4 N m-2. Heat released in this process is used to increase the temperature of 1 mole of Al. If molar heat capacity of Al is 24 J mol-¹K-¹, the temperature of Al increases by
>     (a) 2 K
>     (b) 1K
>     (c) 2/3 K
>     (d) 3/2 K

In the solution, the heat released has been equated to the work done which is

$-P(\mathrm{external})(V_2-V_1)=-4(1-5)=\pu{16 J}$ <--------I don't get this part.

What actually am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: You can't keep the temperature of a perfect gas constant if only work is performed. Heat must be exchanged also.

Answers involving the thermodynamics of ideal gases are logically self-consistent. Start from some logical premises:

If the gas is ideal, then its internal energy depends only on T. Corollary: if the internal energy has changed, T has changed, and vice-versa.

Changes in internal energy are possible through either exchange of heat, or work, or both.

Starting from the above, you can state that:

(1) if a net amount of heat is exchanged with only one other body, but no work is done at all, then T must have changed, because the internal energy must have changed.

(2) if the internal energy has not changed, then T has not changed, and either W=-Q or W=0 and Q=0.